# EFCore : duplication of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have objects like the following :

```
Class Job
{
  int JobId; // PK
  Icollection<Pat> Pats;
}

Class Pat
{
  int PatId; // PK
  int JobId; // FK
  string RelativePath;
}
```

Once added a Job with a collection of Pat, it is no more possible to add a new Job with the same collection of Pat. 
I would like to duplicate Pats for each Job.

Here is what i have done :

```
using (var db = new TransferContext())
{
   for (int i = 1; i<=2; i++)
   {
        var tj = new Job()
        {
            Pats = listto;
        };                        
        await db.TJobs.AddAsync(tj);
   }
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

listto is the collection that i want to duplicate for each Job.

Thanks for your help.

K

Comment: in Job model you have a pats collection, whats the `TransferObjects` in Job?

Comment: Sorry it is misstake. TransferObjects should be read as Pats. Thanks

Comment: If you  would like to duplicate Pats for each Job your PatId must be different because it is a key and must be unique.

Comment: Yes of course ! But i don't create them separatly. Pats are stored automatically when adding Job.
When storing again a new Job with the same Pats they don't get added again. Simply previously created Pats are related to the new job.

Comment: @Kattabomane Yeah and this is a correct behaviour, because in your current model, `Pat` can have one and only one  `Job`. 1) you created Pats without jobs 2) You created Job1 and assigned your created Pats to Job1. 3) You created Job2 and reassigned Pats to a fresh Job2

Comment: Is this possible to achieve this (ie Pats can have Multiple Jobs and vice versa) instead doing a relation table as suggested by the Answer below with many to many relationship ?

Comment: It is not a problem to dupplicate entries in Pat. I have to maintain the list of Pats for a Job.

Comment: I achieved what i wanted by cloning the Pats before setting it to the Job class.
Thanks for all you comments.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are looking for a Many to Many relationship, where you can have a separate set of both Jobs and Pats that can be linked.

You need a `class JobPat` with an Id for each, and then `Job` and `Pat` get a collection of the `JobPat` instead of a direct link.

[Configuring Many to Many Relationships with EF Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration)